# how can I check my rsa passphrase?

Tags: command-line, ssh, passwords, rsa

I think I've forgotten my RSA passphrase *again*.

Is there a way to have my local command line prompt me for it so I can check if I at least what I remember it as is correct, so I don't needlessly change it?

Next time I'm writing it on a post-it ;)

Comment: How are you using the RSA key - SSH login? Web server certificates?

Comment: github and ssh login

Answer (score 66):

Use:

```
ssh-keygen -y

-y      This option will read a private OpenSSH format file and
        print an OpenSSH public key to stdout.
```

Example:

```
$ ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_file
```

This will prompt to enter the passphrase. Given a wrong passphrase it will say "load failed" otherwise it will print the OpenSSH public key to stdout.

Answer (score 10):

Try `ssh-keygen -p`:

```
-p      Requests changing the passphrase of a private key file instead of
        creating a new private key.  The program will prompt for the file
        containing the private key, for the old passphrase, and twice for
        the new passphrase.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Linux or Windows**

If you lose your SSH key passphrase, there's no way to recover it. You'll need to generate [a brand new SSH keypair](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) or [switch to HTTPS cloning](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls) so you can use a personal access token instead.

**Mac**

If you configured your SSH passphrase with the macOS keychain, you may be able to recover it.

- In Finder, search for the Keychain Access app.
- In Keychain Access, search for SSH.
- Double-click on the entry for your SSH key to open a new dialog box.
- In the lower-left corner, select Show password.
- You'll be prompted for your administrative password. Type it into the "Keychain Access" dialog box.
- Your password will be revealed.

Reference: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/recovering-your-ssh-key-passphrase