# Difference between ssh-keygen -y and id_rsa.pub

Tags: macos, ssh, openssh

I used `ssh-keygen -t rsa` to generate a pair of keys. The public key is stored in  the file "id_rsa.pub", which contains "ssh-rsa AAA...idJ tom@toms-MacBook-Pro.local".

Then I used `ssh-keygen -y` (mentioned in [how can I check my rsa passphrase?](https://superuser.com/questions/150123/how-can-i-check-my-rsa-passphrase)) to get the SSH public key. However, the public key obtained using this method contains "ssh-rsa AAA...idJ" only. (i.e. it does not have the last part " tom@toms-MacBook-Pro.local")

I would like to ask why is there a difference in the public key generated via these two methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in the key itself. [The last part is a "comment" field.](https://superuser.com/questions/516912/does-the-right-half-of-the-rsa-public-key-matter?rq=1)

If you're using the traditional-format `id_rsa` key file (the one that starts with "RSA PRIVATE KEY"), it simply did not have any standard place to *store* the comment, so ssh-keygen has nowhere to get it from. (It's a generic key format that OpenSSH adopted because its crypto library already had it.)

The "new" OpenSSH private key format (the one which says "OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY") *does* have a comment field and ssh-keygen can extract it just fine. If you want to convert your private key, you can use `ssh-keygen -p` on new OpenSSH versions; `ssh-keygen -o -p` on slightly older ones, followed by actually setting a new comment using `ssh-keygen -c`.